# Error while calling a static method from a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

While creating a windows form app, I was trying to call a static method in a class named 'Sqlclass' with the below code
 `new SqlScript().Diagnose(txtServer.Text, txtDatabase.Text, txtDeptAdminAlias.Text, "GV_Diagnose.sql");`
Method in the class would look like this:

```
public static SqlDataReader Diagnose(string server,string databasen,string alias,string sqlFile)
        {
            
            string str = Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\" + sqlFile;
            SqlDataReader reader=null;
            if (File.Exists(str))
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(str);
                UtilityClass gUtilityClass = new GUtilityClass("GV");
                string cmdText = fileInfo.OpenText().ReadToEnd().Replace("#USERNAME#", alias);
                SqlConnection connection = gUtilityClass.IsServerConnected();
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
                    try
                    {
                        sqlCommand.CommandText = cmdText;
                       sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File " + str + " is missing.");
            }
            return reader;
        }
```

Now am getting the error "Member 'SqlScript.Diagnose(string, string, string, string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"
Please excuse if I have made anything wrong

Comment: Simply replace `new SqlScript().Diagnose(...)` by `SqlScript.Diagnose(...)`. You can use a static method from a variable/instance.

Comment: Remove the `new`... you can't create an instance of that class and hence, `cannot be accessed with an instance reference` error you're seeing.

Comment: It is _SqlScript().Diagnose(....)_ Static methods are called directly on the class itself not from an instance of that class (new SqlScript). The error message is just saying that

Comment: Thank you Guys.. That Worked!!